# Google Vertex AI GPU only 50% utilized

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nvidia

I am running a custom training job using Google Vertex AI. I am using Nvidia Tesla V100 with 2 accelerators. I am training a ML model but my GPU utilization is only 50% during training.

I am using Nvidia Transfer Learning Toolkit to train an object detection model, and I specified GPUs=2 on the TLT commands.

Any ideas how I can get higher GPU utilization?

Comment: Please provide some information on your configuration. It will be complicated to check what may be wrong without some example.  My first guess is that you may be missing [model_parallelism](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/TLT/tlt-user-guide/text/object_detection/fasterrcnn.html#model-parallelism) in training config.

Comment: Considering that there is no snippet to validate what you are doing, my last recommendation would be to reach GCP and get personalized support  [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)